# Pull 3 cards from a deck - Odds

Tags: probability, card-games

i've been looking for help for some days for this,I have a few simple questions.
Could you fill in the blancs where needed?

situation : i Pull 3 cards from a normal deck of 52 cards, simultaniously.

Question1 : How do i calculate the odds of drawing a street ? (3-4-5)

Question2 : How do i calculate the odds of drawing a flush? ( Diamond - diamond - diamond) 
This one i can figure out but i'd like to see the math behind it :)

Question 3 : How do the odds change (if atall) if more decks are added, lets say 3 total decks?

For Q1 : i can figure out theres 52c3 = 22100 possibilities to draw 3 cards differently.

These are the way you can make a street : 
"1-2-3"
"2-3-4"
"3-4-5"
"4-5-6"
"5-6-7"
"6-7-8"
"7-8-9"
"8-9-10"
"9-10-j"
"10-j-v"
"j-v-k"
Wich comes to a total of 11 solutions.

This is where i am stuck, i assume you have to calculate in how many way you can make these 11 solutions.

Any help would be apreciated :)

Comment: The word is "straight", not "street".  And to count the straights you need to take into account the possible suits.

Comment: Further, you should clarify if you really mean *odds* rather than *probability*.  These are related concepts but the presentation of the final answer will be different.  For instance, the probability of rolling a six on a fair six-sided die is $\frac{1}{6}$ but the *odds* of doing so are $1:5$ for (*or equivalently $5:1$ against*).  It is rare for people in a mathematical setting to actually use odds rather than probability, which makes me suspect that you mistranslated or didn't recognize the distinction between the words.

Comment: As for "*how do the odds change if more decks are added*" for the question of straights... to help facilitate calculations, you may assume each of the suits are distinct between decks, so you have say Deck1Diamonds is different than Deck2Diamonds, and so on... so with three decks, you now effectively have twelve suits.  The calculations are otherwise identical to the one deck case.  For flushes on the other hand, treat the suits across decks as the same... so rather than thirteen diamonds in one deck we have 39 diamonds in three decks, etc...

Comment: You should find the probability of a straight will slightly decrease as more decks are added while the probability of a flush will slightly increase as more decks are added.

Answer (score 1):

For next post I would advise to post your try, not only your questions because it can be a useful guidline for anyone attempting to solve it, this is my try:

1) Since we want 3 consecutive cards, the first one could be any, but once you get that first one our possibilities are reduced. This is a conditioned probability where $$P(\text{3 consecutives cards})=P(\text{Any card})\times P(\text{Any card+1 (any suit)})\times P(\text{Any card+2 (any suit)})$$

Therefore, the probability of drawing any card would be $\frac{52}{52}=1$, the probability of the next card being 4 possible choices (if my first card was 1, the second one must be 2, and there are 4 suits) out of 51, and the probability of the next card would be also 4, but out of 50, leaving:

$$P(\text{3 consecutive cards})=\frac{52}{52}\times \frac{4}{51}\times\frac{4}{50}\approx0.63\%$$

2)This is done with the same line of thought:

$$P(\text{flush})=\frac{52}{52}\times\frac{11}{51}\times\frac{10}{50}\approx4.31\%$$

3) I would say the odds would change but you should try it and see what happened

P.S. On Q1 I assumed you could draw any card on your first draw, but you must substrac two cases which would be Q and K